# Eclipse photon lost java file

Tags: java, windows, recovery, eclipse-photon

I am using windows 10 with eclipse photon. I was working and continuously saving my java file when my computer crashed and restarted. I got a message from eclipse when I started it again and got "unable to rebuild project". I have all my files except the one I was working on. I have already tried going to local history but the last one is from a few hours ago.

Can anyone help me recover my lost java source code?

Comment: Try using Windows Search to find the missing file in the file system.  If Search can't find the file, the chances of recovering it are about zero.  (You may want to take this as a hint to learn about using version control and / or backing up your files.)

Comment: What are some recommended options for version control? Cause I was using github and eclipse failed to keep a recent version. Also what happened was eclipse just nulled out my file so when I opened the java file it was all nulls even tho I consistently saved. D:

Comment: If you used GitHub, and committed / pushed the file, you can get the latest version you pushed back from GitHub (!).  If you didn't commit / push ... well there is no magic.  The point of version control (and backup) is that you do it *frequently enough* that you can recover a *recent* copy if a file is trashed.

Comment: If you are asking if there is a version control system that works if you don't commit ... I don't know of one.  FWIW: I recommend and use `git` with `github`, `bitbucket` (... or any other reputable off-host / off-site repository service) to protect you against corruption / failure of your primary repo.